# Why detective Mills keeps telling a woman to "eat"?

Tags: plot-explanation, dialogue, se7en

In this movie Se7en, detective Mills kicks open John Doe's door against detective Somerset's decision:

- Somerset repetitively tells Mills they need a legal reason to knock on that door.

But Mills recruits a woman who makes a false statement which serves as the legal reason for the two detectives to be there.

When Mills gives this woman some money, he keeps telling her: You eat, you eat.

Why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### This may be a subtitle/translation issue.

As I recall, the vagrant signs a somewhat false statement and is given money with the comment...

> "You get something to eat."

This is to indicate that the vagrant should not spend the money on alcohol but rather on food.

This would seem to be at odds with the [**original script**](http://www.dailyscript.com/scripts/seven_production.html) which had this line instead..

> ```
>       The policeman nods.  Mills grips the vagrant and leads him down
>       the stairs in a hurry, around a bend.  Mills looks up to be sure
>       they're out of the policeman's sight, takes out a wad of cash and
>       shoves it in the vagrant's pocket.
>
>                              MILLS
>               Go drink yourself happy.
> ```

Presumably this was to "lighten up" the character of Mills to a slight extent.

Comment: Wow, Mills tells the vagrant to Go drink yourself happy. I would not want to work with him.